# Alamofire returns different result from what is expected

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am using **Alamofire** at my app and it returns a different response from what it should return (I've tested with Postman several times).

What I am doing is I simply call a webservice which returns a list of JSON objects.
Here is the code if you want to take a look:

```
Alamofire.request(Constants.ENDPOINT_GET_PROF_CALENDAR, method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON{
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess{
            let rawResult = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.parseResponse(json: rawResult)



        }else{
            print("Error getting appointments")
        }
    }
```

For example the response is like this:

```
{"busy": [
    {
        "type": "Busy",
        "date": "2019-08-15",
        "timeslot": "07:00-22:00",
        "address": "No address",
        "id": "41769"
    }, //item 1
    {
        "type": "Busy",
        "date": "2019-08-22",
        "timeslot": "08:00-17:00",
        "address": "αθήνα",
        "id": "41670"
    }, //item 2
    .
    .
    .
}
```

If I make same request with postman it returns more items(A different response) than in Alamofire.
What is going wrong?? It looks like Alamofire returns the same thing again and again. This is really weird to me and I would appreciate it if someone knows what is going on!

Comment: Can you print the Alamofire JSON response before parse? The items count is less than Postman?

Comment: @alxlives No matter what, it looks like Alamofire returns always the same response back.
I omitted to copy and paste the response as it will make the post more difficult to  be read

Comment: Try adding this method before loading the data: `URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()`

Comment: Same thing... I really don't know what is going wrong. Other calls to webservice seems like working well. I am checking my code again and again..

Comment: It looks like a cache issue. Can you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489244/3241041

Comment: Hmm i will try to fix it. The only logical reason for this to happen is that the response is cached and reused! Thank you for your help

Comment: You're welcome. Let us know if this worked for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198267/discussion-between-kwnstantinos-nikoloutsos-and-alxlives).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it was really a cache issue. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728934/alamofire-loading-from-cache-even-when-cache-policy-set-to-reloadignoringlocalan/46489244#46489244) solution, we could do something like this:

```
 var req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: Constants.ENDPOINT_GET_PROF_CALENDAR)!)
 req.httpMethod = "GET"
 req.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 req.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

 Alamofire.request(req).validate().responseJSON { response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            let rawResult = JSON(response.result.value!)
            self.parseResponse(json: rawResult)
        }else{
            print("Error getting appointments")
        }
    }
```