# how to ignore cached response using Alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, urlsession

Using Alamofire with configurations like this, leading to **error -999 request cancelled**

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
    configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    sessionManager.request(url,
                              method: methodType,
                              parameters: resource.parameters,
                              headers: resource.headers)
```

However when i use it like this, directly it works fine, but it caches the responses ..

```
Alamofire.request(url,
                          method: methodType,
                          parameters: resource.parameters,
                          headers: resource.headers)
```

I need to ignore the cached data, and using the first is not working .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable caching in Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199494/how-to-disable-caching-in-alamofire)

Comment: @Rishab his solution is not working for me .

Comment: I don't think caching is your real problem here. I think you should look into why your first code is returning -999 error. What happens if you remove `timeoutIntervalForRequest` and `requestCachePolicy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are getting this error, but there are a number of ways to solve this error.

1.You can add timestamp to your API url so so that you would never get a cached response.

```
extension Date {
    func toMillis() -> Int64! {
        return Int64(self.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)
    }
} 

let currentTimeStamp = Date().toMillis()!
let url = "https://example.com?timestamp=\(currentTimeStamp)"
```

2. You can do something like:

   ```
   var req = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "<URL>")!)
   req.httpMethod = "GET"
   req.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
   req.setValue("<Auth KEY>", forHTTPHeaderField:"Authorization" )
   req.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    Alamofire.request(req).validate().responseJSON { response in ...
   ```

taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46489244/5962076)

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, the code wasn't getting formatted properly

Comment: the 2nd way, can u give an example on the 1st way

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: shouldn't my api be supporting a parameter like that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198876/discussion-between-varun-malhotra-and-mohmmad-s).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this (examples use Alamofire 5):

Use an `ephemeral` `URLSessionConfiguration`:

```swift
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral
configuration.headers = .default
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)
```

Use a `URLSessionConfiguration` without a `URLCache` instance:

```swift
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.af.default
configuration.urlCache = nil
let session = Session(configuration: configuration)
```

Set an issued `URLRequest`'s `cachePolicy` to `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData`, which should prevent the storing of its response:

```swift
var request = URLRequest(...)
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
session.request(request).response...
```

Use Alamofire 5's `CachedResponseHandler` API to prevent caching on a per request basis:

```swift
session.request(...).cacheResponse(using: ResponseCacher.doNotCache).response...
```

Answer (score 0):

-> Did you try removing cacheResponse before requesting again?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47869125/9298652

-> Or try setting NSURLConnectionDelegate's willCacheResponse method to nil to prevent responses from caching.